# NodeJS+Express looking for views in the wrong directory

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I just finished a NodeJS project, but I'm having issues with the views being setup properly. Here's my project structure:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin/
├── migrations/
├── models/
├── node_modules/
├── public/
├── routes.js
├── settings.js
├── storage/
├── views/
└── www
```

Here's how I setup my views for the app (in app.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views");
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({defaultLayout: "main"}));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

Then, in the `www` file, I require `app.js` (which exports the `app` object), where a few other things are setup. The problem is that I can't run `pm2 start www`, because it starts looking for the views in the wrong path. Instead of `/var/www/project/views`, it's looking in `/var/www/views`. Right now I'm manually going into the project root and running `node www`, and that's the only way that the views path is set correctly. How do I stop this craziness?

Comment: have you tried setting the path to something like `app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");` ?